# IQueryable<> is losing its initial type after Linq Skip/Take

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection

Can someone explain how to avoid the following situation?

I have a variable called **data** that is an `IQueryable<>`. As you can see before calling Skip/Take on it, the runtime knows of its exact type (`IQueryable<...Module>`).

[image]

After doing Skip/Take the variable data becomes an `IQueryable< object>`.

[image]

I want it to retain the original type it had before executing the Skip/Take. I do not know the exact type inside <> before a method that fills the **data** variable is executed. I know it afterwards and I can get the `Type` which I want to use in order to cast the Skip/Take back to the original type. How can I do that?

PS1: The collection has been returned by a method that returns an `IQueryable< object>`

PS2: Until the skip/take it behaves like an `IQueryable< ...module>`.

Comment: You have answered your own question here - it's because you have a collection of `IQueryable<Object>` to begin with. The reason you are seeing what the actual type it is at runtime - that is just debugger helpfulness.

Comment: Take and Skip are a generic methods so have you tried .Take<Sales.Module>(...) ?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius That is partially true. It behaves as a <Sales.Module> all the way to the end of the method if the Skip/Take does not execute.

Comment: @SimplyGed I do not know it is a Sales.Module beforehand. I know that only during runtime, when a method that fills the data variable executes. I wonder if by getting the Type, I can cast the Skip/Take to that type with reflection.

Comment: @Midas what do you mean by that?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Example: if I use Dynamic Linq to do a select on a property of the class Module, it will execute without a problem. If the flow enters the condition where the Skip/Take executes, the same dynamic Linq select will throw an exception that the type object does not contain that field.

Answer (score 1):

Your collection is of `IQueryable<Object>` prior to executing `Skip` and `Take`. You'll need to cast your collection to its exact type.

Comment: I do not know the exact type beforehand. I can get it through reflection, so my question would that be how can I use the reflected type in order to cast the Skip/Take result back to an IQueryable<ReflectedType>? I have edited my question regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

If your method returns an `IQueryable<object>`, that is all the code will know about. If you're sure of the type you can use an `OfType<Module>()` or `Cast<Module>()` linq call as appropriate to get them back to the type YOU expect rather than the type the code expects.

EDIT: After reading your comments more on the original post it almost sounds like your function that returns `IQueryable<object>` should actually be made into a generic function that returns `IQueryable<T>` so that you won't have this problem in the first place. This is quickly seeming more and more to be an XY problem. If this answer becomes invalid I'll remove it.

Comment: I am not sure of the type, until the method that fills the "data" variable is executed. Then I can get the type (Type) through reflection. I want to use that in order to cast the skip result to that specific Type.

Comment: Second on this. Generic would solve this immediately